# jQuery addClass and removeClass event has weird effect on hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to create a list of menu that when you hover on each it will show the other content. It is now working though yet every time you hover on each item it will create a space on the other list item.

Here's the sample code.

```
<ul class="test111">
    <li><span class="testCont">Another</span><a href="#" class="testmenu">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><span class="testCont">Another1</span><a href="#" class="testmenu">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.test111{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
.test111 li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    height:36px;
    display: block;
}
.test111 li .testCont{
    background:#0f0;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
}
.test111 li a{
    background:#0ff;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$('.testCont').hide();

$('.test111 li').mouseover(function(){

    $('.test111 li').removeClass('hoverME');
    $(this).addClass('hoverME');
    $('.hoverME .testCont').show();

});
$('.test111 li').mouseout(function(){
    $('.testCont').hide();
});
```

[SAmple output here](https://jsfiddle.net/qfoz30fe/)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `float:right;` to `.test111 li a`

```js
$('.testCont').hide();

$('.test111 li').mouseover(function(){

    $('.test111 li').removeClass('hoverME');
    $(this).addClass('hoverME');
    $('.hoverME .testCont').show();

});
$('.test111 li').mouseout(function(){
    $('.testCont').hide();
});
```

```css
.test111{position: fixed; right:0; margin-right:0;}
.test111 li{margin-bottom: 10px; list-style: none; height:36px; display: block;}
.test111 li .testCont{background:#0f0; width:100px; float:left; height: 100%;}
.test111 li a{background:#0ff; width:50px; float:left; height: 100%;float:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test111">
    <li><span class="testCont">Another</span><a href="#" class="testmenu">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><span class="testCont">Another1</span><a href="#" class="testmenu">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're Welcome @justch4 .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need. But I am guessing here. Change the last line in CSS:

```
.test111 li a{background:#0ff; width:50px; float:right; height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the css position property of test111 to relative.
It should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smooth variant using CSS `opacity` and jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //$('.testCont').hide();

  $('.test111 li').mouseover(function(){


    $('.test111 li').removeClass('hoverME');
    $(this).addClass('hoverME');
    $('.hoverME .testCont').stop().animate({"opacity":1},600);


  });
  $('.test111 li').mouseout(function(){
    $('.testCont').stop().animate({"opacity":0},600);;
  });

});
```

```css
.test111{
  position: fixed; 
  right:0; 
  margin-right:0;
}
.test111 li{
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  list-style: none; 
  height:36px; 
  display: block;
}
.test111 li .testCont{
  background:#0f0; 
  width:100px; 
  float:left; 
  height: 100%;
}
.test111 li a{
  background:#0ff; 
  width:50px; 
  float:left; 
  height: 100%;
}
.testCont{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test111">
  <li><span class="testCont">Another</span><a href="#" class="testmenu">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><span class="testCont">Another1</span><a href="#" class="testmenu">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><span class="testCont">Another1</span><a href="#" class="testmenu">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```